Which join flow is faster; joining with parameter of function or with the parent table data in postgresql
I have a parent table TABLE_A with a, b and c columns and table TABLE_B with a, b and d columns; I have written a function in Postgresql to join these tables, which function query will be faster. NOTE: both a and b columns of the TABLE_A  and TABLE_B are indexed, and a and b will be constant values that won't change throughout the function.
QUERY 1: 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A as ta 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_B as tb ON tb.a = ta.a and tb.b = tb.ta.b
WHERE
   ta.a = $1 and 
   ta.b = $2

QUERY 2:
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A as ta 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_B as tb ON tb.a = $1 and tb.b = $2
WHERE
   ta.a = $1 and 
   ta.b = $2

NOTE: $1 and $2 are the function's first and second parameters, respectively.

Implement both approaches and run tests to evaluate their relative performance against actual data. There is little value in asking others to theorize (guess) about which will be faster.

The performance analysis with actual data didn't provide much difference in the end, that's why I want to know which approach will be better theoretically

The question lacks sufficient detail to elicit more than opinion. Among the variables that might affect the relative performance are the PostgreSQL version, volume of data, and the data's characteristics (statistics). Use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) to see the actual execution plans. It is possible that both approaches produce the same plan since the query engine can rearrange the queries into semantically equivalent forms. If the performance is nearly identical, then choose the one that more clearly expresses the operation (I'd go with query 1).

It sounds like you answered your own question when you tested "there wasn't much difference". That means there was some difference, and you now know which one is faster.

You typically want to compare the execution plans to see the difference in the two statements. You will use EXPLAIN to this purpose:
PREPARE stmt1(int, int) AS  
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A as ta 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_B as tb ON tb.a = ta.a and tb.b =  ta.b
WHERE
   ta.a = $1 and 
   ta.b = $2;
  
EXPLAIN EXECUTE stmt1(42, 42); 

which results in
QUERY PLAN                                                                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.58..16.64 rows=1 width=16)                     |
  ->  Index Scan using tab_a_b on table_a ta  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8)|
        Index Cond: (b = 42)                                                  |
        Filter: (a = 42)                                                      |
  ->  Index Scan using tab_b_b on table_b tb  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8)|
        Index Cond: (b = 42)                                                  |
        Filter: (a = 42)                                                      |

If you repeat this with the second statements (omitted here for brevity) you'll see the identical result, which provides the answer that the two statements will behave identical.
It is no surprise, such trivial transformation of the predicates are performed by the RDBMs automatically:
ta.a = $1   and ta.a = tb.a  =>  tb.a = $1

You are wellcome! What you also can see from the execution plan is, that the two indices on aand b are not optimal as only one of them is used. You may profit from index on (a,b)
